# Chaining Filters together

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Given the following:

```
instances = Catalog.objects.filter(
                                Q(imdb_url=imdb_url)
                               |Q(isan=isan)
                               |Q(amg_video_id=amg_video_id)
)
```

How would I do the same in the following format, chaining each together:

```
instances = Catalog.objects.all()
if imdb_url:
    instances = instances.filter(imdb_url = imdb_url) # OR
if isan:
    instances = instances.filter(isan = isan) # OR
if amg:
    instances = instances.filter(amg = amg) # OR
```

The above gives me the equivalent of:

```
instances = Catalog.objects.filter(imdb_url=imdb_url).filter(isan=isan).filter(amg=amg)
```

How would I do the eqivalent of the `Q` in the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty `Q` object and OR with others accordingly using `|=`:

```
q = Q()

if imdb_url:
    q |= Q(imdb_url=imdb_url)
if isan:
    q |= Q(isan=isan) 
if amg:
    q |= Q(amg=amg)

instances = Catalog.objects.filter(q)
```

Answer (score 1):

The union operator for querysets is `|`

```
instances = Catalog.objects.none()
if imdb_url:
    instances |= instances.filter(imdb_url=imdb_url)
if isan:
    instances |= instances.filter(isan=isan)
if amg:
    instances |= instances.filter(amg=amg)
```